# Javascript: How to add properties to a class object that are part of class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have been thinking if this could be done. If yes, how? I am fairly new to javaScript world so please bear with me.

**To best explain what I am trying to achieve, I will provide a small example:**
[PLAYGROUND](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false&strictNullChecks=false&strictFunctionTypes=false&strictPropertyInitialization=false&strictBindCallApply=false&noImplicitThis=false&noImplicitReturns=false&alwaysStrict=false&declaration=false#code/FAAloYwGwQwZziAIgewgVwLYFMB2AXEAb1BDICN4BLCJbfGKqOALhACFrb7HmBuUmQgpccfACd0EfCnEAKFOQBWqDDgIsYuAJ4BKYoLJH8ACypwAdJTg06DJogC8IXNgDuHLnd5wFy1Vh4%20LoCRmEgAPQRpuZWXjwOIM4A8srY0hbwNgDmuHIxlta2CcwANCCKKmiBBHE23PbMIYYAvsBtwNBZnvXeiSRh%20NoADthsYuJUuNmhRhDi2DD42AAmSEtjyBuzQiITUjLylQHq%20Jo6%20gPhZAUWQ6NJIABETzvht-OLy2sbj64e62WcmaYTaHSg9AqykeRCKDR8bCI902TxW4hgADN8E8WuUoFNsH1mCwiPjXFQViwAIwAJgAzKUqMtMAA5GA4FhPJnYVns7A4kBtEAQwgrNB-dzIaqnPxKXSQPYoCEWKAobJyMUQXRAA)

```
class Document {
    basicDetails: BasicDetails;
    constructor(objDocument:any) {
        this.basicDetails = new BasicDetails(objDocument);
        //this.basicDetails = Object.assign(this.basicDetails, objDocument.basicDetails);
    }
}

class BasicDetails {
    type: string;
    createdDate: Date;
    constructor(objDocument:any) {
        this.type = "";
        this.createdDate = new Date();
    }
}
```

As you can see, the Document Class has just one property called basicDetails. But the `objDocument` that it's constructor accepts has not only basicDetails object but also other properties.

```
let obj = {basicDetails: {type: "draft"}, lineDetails:{lineid:123,itemName:"itemName"} }
 let doc = new Document(obj)
 console.log(doc)
```

**The output of the above code is naturally:**

```
  {
  "basicDetails": {
    "type": "",
    "createdDate": "2020-12-03T08:02:59.780Z"
  }
}
```

**But I want the output to be:**

```
  {
  "basicDetails": {
    "type": "",
    "createdDate": "2020-12-03T08:02:59.780Z"
  },
   "lineDetails":{"lineid":123,"itemName":"itemName"} }
}
```

Whatever properties that are part of `objDocument:any` in addition to basicDetails must be added automatically as is. And the properties should not have to be added out side of the class.

```
let doc = new Document(obj)
doc["lineDetails] = obj.lineDetials // not acceptable
```

Comment: I'd advise against this approach. It's *possible* but makes the `Document` object hard to use, since the properties now depend on how it was instantiated. You can probably add a second property `otherDetails` that is of type `readonly Record<string, unknown>` for example and anything that's *not* part of `basicDetails` will be there. This keeps the `Document` object API more stable.

Comment: @VLAZ actually, the nature of Document is quite dynamic.  The data which going to be sent to us  would look like : `{basicDetials:{}, .. insert anything at all..}` so we don't know and don't care what is being sent apart from basicDetails. Which is fixed. Everything else.. we just store it in DB without caring about its validity.

Comment: @VLAZ I understand that you are suggesting that whatever is variable should be kept in fixed property `otherDetails` but we don't have control over it. All we know is we will get a fixed structure basicDetails at the root level.

Comment: @VLAZ while I think over possibilities. Could you please explain how it could be done (the original ask)?

Comment: Is it intended that the constructor of `BasicDetails` ignores the argument given to it?

Comment: @trincot No. The argument given to BasicDetails will be used to initialize properties. This is a quick snippet that I wrote to help people understand my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract the basic details from the object that is passed to the Document constructor, and identify what is all the rest, using destructuring with the spread syntax.

In this demo I commented out the typescript parts, so it can run here:

```js
class Document {
    basicDetails /*: BasicDetails */;
    constructor(objDocument /*:any*/) {
        let {basicDetails, ...rest} = objDocument;
        this.basicDetails = new BasicDetails(basicDetails);
        Object.assign(this, rest);
    }
}

class BasicDetails {
    type /*: string */;
    createdDate /*: Date */;
    constructor(objDocument /*:any */) {
        this.type = objDocument.type;
        this.createdDate = new Date();
    }
}

let obj = {basicDetails: {type: "draft"}, lineDetails:{lineid:123,itemName:"itemName"} };
let doc = new Document(obj);
console.log(doc);
```

Comment: wow, I was not aware of `...rest` that is pretty cool. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can first make your life easier by extracting the constructor options for `Document`. Since you want a `basicDetails` on the root level and then potentially anything else, this becomes:

```typescript
interface DocumentOptions {
    basicDetails: any,
    [key: string]: unknown
}
```

This now means that you can get at least some type safety and prevent instantiating `Document` without `basicDetails`.

Now you can change the constructor to extract `basicDetails` for instantiating the `BasicDetails` object and then assign everything else to the current instance. Providing an [index signature] for `Document` signifies that it can have any amount of any properties. Making those properties `readonly` means that you're not allowed to change them:

```typescript
class Document {
    basicDetails: BasicDetails;
    readonly [key: string]: unknown
    constructor({ basicDetails, ...otherDetails } : DocumentOptions) {
        this.basicDetails = new BasicDetails(basicDetails);

        Object.assign(this, otherDetails);
    }
}
```

You can further increase the type safety by assigning correct types for the constructor of `BasicDetails` then use the [`ConstructorParameters`] utility type to make sure the correct things are passed to `Document`:

```typescript
interface DocumentOptions {
    basicDetails: ConstructorParameters<typeof BasicDetails>[0],
    [key: string]: unknown
}

class Document {
    basicDetails: BasicDetails;
    readonly [key: string]: unknown
    constructor({ basicDetails, ...otherDetails } : DocumentOptions) {
        this.basicDetails = new BasicDetails(basicDetails);

        Object.assign(this, otherDetails);
    }
}

class BasicDetails {
    type: string;
    createdDate: Date;
    constructor(objDocument: {}) {
        this.type = "";
        this.createdDate = new Date();
    }
}


let obj = { basicDetails: { type: "draft" }, lineDetails: { lineid: 123, itemName: "itemName" } }
let doc = new Document(obj)
doc["lineDetails"] = obj.lineDetials // not acceptable
console.log(doc)
```

If you want to be even more future proof, then you can accept the entire parameter list for `BasicDetails`, so if the constructor changes in the future, you don't need to change `Document` or `DocumentOptions`:

```
interface DocumentOptions {
    basicDetails: ConstructorParameters<typeof BasicDetails>, //no index
    [key: string]: unknown
}

class Document {
    basicDetails: BasicDetails;
    readonly [key: string]: unknown
    constructor({ basicDetails, ...otherDetails } : DocumentOptions) {
        this.basicDetails = new BasicDetails(...basicDetails);
//pass everything                            ^^^
        Object.assign(this, otherDetails);
    }
}
```

However, with that said, I'd advise collecting all other properties in a separate property instead, as that would make the `Document` API more stable:

```
interface DocumentOptions {
    basicDetails: ConstructorParameters<typeof BasicDetails>[0],
    [key: string]: unknown
}

class Document {
    basicDetails: BasicDetails;
    readonly otherDetails: Readonly<Record<string, unknown>>
    constructor({ basicDetails, ...otherDetails }: DocumentOptions) {
        this.basicDetails = new BasicDetails(basicDetails);
        this.otherDetails = otherDetails;
    }

    serialise() {
        return Object.assign({}, {basicDetails: this.basicDetails.serialise()}, this.otherDetails)
    }
}

class BasicDetails {
    type: string;
    createdDate: Date;
    constructor(objDocument: {}) {
        this.type = "";
        this.createdDate = new Date();
    }

    serialise() {
        return { type: this.type };
    }
}

let obj = { basicDetails: { type: "draft" }, lineDetails: { lineid: 123, itemName: "itemName" } }
let doc = new Document(obj)
doc.otherDetails["lineDetails"] = obj.lineDetails // not acceptable
console.log(doc.serialise())
```

I've added a `serialise` method for convenience - it will output the information as you expect:

```
{
  "basicDetails": {
    "type": "",
    "createdDate": "2020-12-03T09:09:30.355Z"
  },
  "lineDetails": {
    "lineid": 123,
    "itemName": "itemName"
  }
}
```

It also happens to give you cloning functionality for free, since it outputs the exact same data that the constructor consumes, so you can do this:

```typescript
let obj = { basicDetails: { type: "draft" }, lineDetails: { lineid: 123, itemName: "itemName" } }
let doc1 = new Document(obj)

//free cloning
let doc2 = new Document(doc1.serialise());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an improvement from @trincot answer. First of all the design is not the best, you should inject an already created class into your Document constructor.

```
class Document {
    basicDetails /*: BasicDetails */;
    constructor(basicDetails /*:BasicDetails*/, rest : /*:any*/) {
       this.basicDetails = basicDetails
       Object.assign(this, rest);
    }
}
```

That is one of the SOLID principles ( Dependency Injection ).

```
let obj = { basicDetails: { type: "draft" }, lineDetails:{ lined : 123, itemName : "itemName" } };

class BasicDetails {
    type /*: string */;
    createdDate /*: Date */;
    constructor(basicDetails /*:basicDetails */) {
        this.type = basicDetails.type;
        this.createdDate = new Date();
    }
}

const { basicDetails, ...rest } = obj

const doc = new Document( new BasicDetails(basicDetails), rest )
```